# HTML: url = <name var>

Tags: html, href, var

As `href` argument, I would like to put a variable.

Instead of:

```
<p><a href="http://www.google.com">Go to Google</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to write something as:

```
<html>
<body>

var link = "http://www.google.com"
<p><a href=link>Go to Google</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<p><a id="some-link">Some link</a> is here</p>

<script>
  var link = 'http://www.google.com';

  var someLink = document.querySelector('#some-link');
  someLink.setAttribute('href', link);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `script` tag executes javascript actions. This one specifically sets the `href` of the given item with the `some-link` id. The `#` means "element with the id".

You can try it over here. https://jsfiddle.net/94ct5hvr/

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with angularJS

```
<html>
 <body ng-app="App" ng-controller="myApp">

<p><a href={{link}}>Go to Google</a></p>

</body> 
</html>
```

On the javascript side you can do:

```
var app = angular.module('App',[]);

app.controller(function($scope){
   $scope.link = "http://www.google.com;
});
```